# Is it an anti-pattern to keep a database in a container?

Tags: database, docker, containers, devops

I have a question regarding best practices with containers. **Is it an anti-pattern to have a database in a container?**

I've seen implementations of DBs in containers a couple times now and I'd love to get y'all's thoughts on it. From my understanding, containers should be lightweight and effectively stateless. They should also operate as cattle, not pets (as in, easily destroyed and you don't rely on one container staying to perform business functions).

From what I know of DBs, they aren't usually cattle, and depending on the application they aren't lightweight. They're also pretty much inherently stateful.

It's pretty clear that I'm skeptical of DBs being hosted in containers, but I'd really love to hear what y'all think. I'm not too familiar with DBA work so hearing from those with more experience (*especially if you've implemented it and have experiences you can talk to*) would be great.

Comment: Also, if there's a better place to ask this, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum for this.

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a great question, though its a bit broad.  It completely depends on what exactly you are running and how you plan your workloads.

The thing to keep in mind about containers is that there really isnt any magic here.  Containers ultimately boil down to kernel level (cgroup) limits imposed on a process and the orchestration layer (eg Kubernetes or CloudFoundry Diego) are responsible to reacting to when the container is killed off for crossing these limits (eg out of memory).

In general, there are a number of high level factors to keep in mind

- What are the data durability requirements for this project
- What are the workloads (eg hourly spikes, unpredictable load, etc)
- What is your uptime SLA and can you clients handle failing over to new masters in your data tier gracefully
- Most importantly, is containerization the right pattern for what your project's data tier is trying to achieve.

Beyond this, you have to look at characteristics of your orchestration environment.  If you need to be able to persist disk contents, you need to make sure you pick a container orchestrator that is able to fill this requirement.

You may have something like a sharded MongoDB cluster using the In-Memory engine for a caching layer that requires a bit more capability than a typical key value store like memcache (eg ability to query/filter the cache itself).  Depending on your project's requirements, it may be perfectly fine to lose this "cache" layer and rebuild it on demand.

In other workloads.  You could run something like enterpriseDB ARK to provide clustered, highly available, containerized PostgreSQL deployments on top of Kubernetes.  This comes with its own challenges, but it enables you to implement a service broker model in your micro services architecture to deploy and persist the data tier for each of your micro services in a way that mitigates a monolithic data tier which is prone to chatty neighbor problems in this type of architecture.